# is it a way to do a "store" operation without fetching in case of cache miss

Tags: caching, cpu-cache

when using a standard memory store operation (maximal possible is 8 bytes in standard architecture) to an address that is not in the cache, a cache miss occurs because the granularity of the cache is greater than 8 bytes. (usually 64 bytes)
But in some cases I know for sure that no read will be performed from the corresponding cache line before I write all the 64 bytes, so I am looking for some way to tell the CPU to not fetch the memory from main memory hence to avoid the cache miss.
Is it such way indeed?
I also dont care that in case that the CPU will decide to evacuate the cache line before I finished writing all of it, then garabge will be written to main memory in addresses that I didnt write within the cache line